# Is there an equivalent of 'yarn why' for pnpm?

Tags: pnpm

There is a particular sub-dependency of my project that is failing to install properly in pnpm. I'm not sure why the dependency (`es5-ext`) is required.

When using yarn, I can ask "yarn why [package-name]" to find out why a package is needed.

Is there an equivalent in pnpm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pnpm why es5-ext` will work with pnpm. See the docs: https://pnpm.io/cli/why

Comment: Ah! I was tripped up by the error message I received with `pnpm why`: "ERR_PNPM_MISSING_PACKAGE_NAME  `pnpm why` requires the package name". Thank you.

Comment: It's missing from `pnpm --help` btw

Comment: @JeanClaveau `pnpm --help` doesn't print all the commands at the moment as there are too many commands and it would be hard to read the output. It prints the most frequently used commands. But maybe `pnpm why` should be added.